# Divert traffic when site down

Tags: offline

Any bright ideas on how to fallback to an HTML page "Website Offline" when the main box holding the Wordpress multi-site is down?

Real scenario; fully operational SAAS built on cloud vps. Cloud VPS has issues, emergency rebuild of SAN, our box goes offline. Is there a way to direct traffic to a specific page in the event of melt-down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running Nginx, it is easier to implement a similar scenario with an isolated server running Nginx alone.

In Nginx, the [HttpUpstreamModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUpstreamModule) can be configured to divert the traffic to a completely different domain running on a different server. For example, if your site is yoursite.com, it is easy to divert the visitors to status.yoursite.com when the main site (running on a different server) is down for some reason.

Comment: Bingo. That's exactly what I was looking and hoping for. Thank you sir! Yup running a custom cocktail that includes nginx instead of apache.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on quite how down the site is, you might be able to handle it through .htaccess with `ErrorDocument`, maybe something in the 500 series of errors would suit you?

Comment: oooohhh. There's an idea, but yeah down, as in, hard-core down. Nothing showing in the browser down. Like nothing is even there....

Comment: I'm not sure if that is possible...if your server is that gone, it probably can't tell anyone to go anywhere. You might be able to do something with your domain registrar MAYBE...but I doubt it. Probably just have to deal with the downtime and have good sysadmins so you minimize it